# User_data not working in Launch configuration. Is it a problem with my security group or my Launch configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-auto-scaling

I am currently learning Terraform and I need help with regard to the below code. I want to create a simple architecture of an autoscaling group of EC2 instances behind an Application load balancer. The setup gets completed but when I try to access the application endpoint, it gets timed out. When I tried to access the EC2 instances, I was unable to (because EC2 instances were in a security group allowing access from the ALB security group only). I changed the instance security group ingress values and ran the user_data script manually following which I reverted the changes to the instance security group to complete my setup.

My question is why is my setup not working via the below code? Is it because the access is being restricted by the load balancer security group or is my launch configuration block incorrect?

```yaml
data "aws_ami" "amazon-linux" {
  most_recent = true
  owners      = ["amazon"]

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["amzn2-ami-kernel-5.10-hvm-2.0.20220426.0-x86_64-gp2"]
  }
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
 state = "available"
}

module "vpc" {
  source                = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version               = "3.14.0"

  name                  = "main-vpc"
  cidr                  = "10.0.0.0/16"

  azs                   = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  public_subnets        = ["10.0.4.0/24","10.0.5.0/24","10.0.6.0/24"]
  enable_dns_hostnames  = true
  enable_dns_support    = true

}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "TestLC" {
  name_prefix = "Lab-Instance-"
  image_id = data.aws_ami.amazon-linux.id
  instance_type = "t2.nano"
  key_name = "CloudformationKeyPair"
  user_data = file("./user_data.sh")
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.TestInstanceSG.id]

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "TestASG" {
  min_size = 1
  max_size = 3
  desired_capacity = 2
  launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.TestLC.name
  vpc_zone_identifier = module.vpc.public_subnets
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "TestListener"{
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.TestLB.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"
  default_action {
    type = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.TestTG.arn
  }
}

resource "aws_lb" "TestLB" {
  name              = "Lab-App-Load-Balancer"
  internal          = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups   = [aws_security_group.TestLoadBalanceSG.id]
  subnets           = module.vpc.public_subnets
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "TestTG" {
  name = "LabTargetGroup"
  port = "80"
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_attachment" "TestAutoScalingAttachment" {
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.TestASG.id
  lb_target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.TestTG.arn
}



resource "aws_security_group" "TestInstanceSG" {
  name = "LAB-Instance-SecurityGroup"
  ingress{
  from_port = 80
  to_port = 80
  protocol = "tcp"
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.TestLoadBalanceSG.id]
  }
  ingress{
  from_port = 22
  to_port = 22
  protocol = "tcp"
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.TestLoadBalanceSG.id]
  }

  egress{
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.TestLoadBalanceSG.id]
  }
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_security_group" "TestLoadBalanceSG" {
  name = "LAB-LoadBalancer-SecurityGroup"
  ingress{
  from_port = 80
  to_port = 80
  protocol = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress{
  from_port = 22
  to_port = 22
  protocol = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress{
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }


  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
}
```

Comment: Your `user_data` fetches something over the network? `ssh` is nothing to do with user_data except you have put `egress` rules or any `firewall` in between. Sometimes internal loadbalancers cut-off access to internet. It's the case with Azure Standard LB.

Comment: Thanks Harsha. It is as I suspect that the problem is not with user data but with the ingress rules (not egress). The ingress rules for the instance state that request has to come from security group only and not from the internet. How do i correct this problem?